# magic of array.prototype.slice.call(X).concat(array.prototype.slice.call(X))

Tags: javascript

I have a function:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function() {
var fn = this;
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
var object = args.shift();
    return function(){
      return fn.apply(object, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)));
    };
};
```

if I do:

```
var l = [1, 2, {one: one}];
console.log(array.prototype.slice.call(l).concat(array.prototype.slice.call(l)));
```

I get double l content. Do you explain me please for what this magic statement is in the function above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference between your example and the below code is that in the code below the value of arguments is not the same at both lines:

```
Function.prototype.bind = function() { // f1
var fn = this;
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); // arguments of f1
var object = args.shift();
    return function(){ // f2
      return fn.apply(object, args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))); // arguments of f2
    };
};
```

Commented a use case to help you understand:

```
// Usage:
var boundFunc = func.bind(obj, arg1, arg2);
boundFunc(arg3, arg4);

Function.prototype.bind = function() { // f1
var fn = this;  //fn will be initialized to func
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments); // args will be [obj, arg1, arg2]
var object = args.shift(); // object will be obj, args will be [arg1, arg2]
    return function(){ // f2
      // arguments is array-like [arg3, arg4]
      var allArgs = args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)) // allArgs is [arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4]
      return fn.apply(object, allArgs); // func called with obj as this and arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4 as arguments 
    };
};
```

Notes:

`Array.prototype.slice` when called with 0 arguments (or with 0 as argument) creates a clone of the array passed to it. It can also be called on array-like objects as arguments or NodeList objects to create an array with the same items.